# How to get a Printer/scanner Seen on a network with different IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, printer

I have a Printer on a fixed LAN IP and it works fine (IP 192.168.0.xx) but I have a secure PC from work that uses a different IP (10.x.x.x range) and I can only see my printer if I go off vpn. How can I change my router to allow for the vpn PC to see the printer scanner without losing the vpn security? (NOTE: I am unable to modify the vpn PC in any way so changing the PC Ip is not possible but I can set-up my router/printer)!

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the access would be whitelisting either the internal IP address of the printer, or your entire private IP range in the VPN client settings.

As you can't modify the VPN settings, you should talk to the IT crowd of your employer. Maybe even better is giving a business case to your manager about the need to access your private printer while VPN:d to the company network, and let him arrange it with the company IT.